# Create DataColumns and Dataset witout database by code

Tags: vb.net

I add Dataset1 and then I add a DataTable named (FACTORY) and then I add 3 DataColumns (DataColumns1,DataColumns2,DataColumns3) so that these columns I use them in CrystalReport1 to print my DataGridView1 after query which contains 3 columns (Name,Phone,Address).
My code for print work very well but i want remove completely this Dataset1(XSD) and if it is possible replace this Dataset and DataColumns and create theme only by code.
This is my code for print :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FACTORY As New DataTable
    FACTORY.TableName = "FACTORY"
    Dim col1 As New DataColumn("FirstName", GetType(String))
    Dim col2 As New DataColumn("LastName", GetType(String))
    Dim col3 As New DataColumn("Phone", GetType(String))
    FACTORY.Columns.Add(col1)
    FACTORY.Columns.Add(col2)
    FACTORY.Columns.Add(col3)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DS.Tables.Add(FACTORY)
       For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        DS.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr.Cells(0).Value, dr.Cells(1).Value, dr.Cells(2).Value)
       Next
    Dim rp As New CrystalReport1
    rp.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))
        'rp.SetDataSource(DS.Tables("FACTORY"))
    Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rp
    Form1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

https://e.top4top.net/p_1210a4l3m1.jpg

Comment: So go ahead. What's stopping you? I'm guessing that you haven't actually done any research on the subject, because information and examples would be very easy to find.

Comment: No dear sir .. I did a lot of research in several days .. but as I am a beginner I could not get to the good and easy idea .. in any case Thank you for your opinion

Comment: If you really did do several days of research and weren't able to come up with anything at all then I hope that that says something about your research skills, because the alternative is of grave concern, beginner or not. I just searched the web for *"create dataset datatable datacolumn in code vb.net"* and found examples all over, including on this very site, in a matter of seconds. If you search for cat videos then you're not going to find much of use to programming, so try using relevant search terms.

Comment: This great Forum is to help beginners like me but it's not o Forum to give advices.I really found a lot examples but i could not adapt them with my code.Thank you

Comment: The way this site works is that you make an attempt and, if it doesn't work, you show us what you did and explain how it behaves and how that differs from your expectations. If you haven't made any attempt, it's too soon to be posting here. There's very little to create a `DataTable` and adding some columns. There's virtually no adaptation required. If you can't at least make an effort, you need to spend more time learning the basics. This site is not about teaching you how to program. It's about answering specific questions you have about your code. No code means no questions about it.

Comment: Excuse me for this question, what is exactly your need? Do you want to know how to create a dataset and a datatable (with columns) programatically?

Comment: Thank you laancelot .. yes exactly that's good I want to know and learn to do this thing programmatically and in addition my real reason is that I hate working with Dataset (Xsd)

Answer (score 1):

Learning the basics can sometimes be confusing, so I'll type you a quick example. You may have further questions, don't hesitate to ask away. Of course, although I'm always willing to help, I would like to point out that jmcilhninney is right about two things he mentioned in his rant: first, you're more likely to get help here if you have a precise problem. This is not a place where you ask for "how-to ...". Second, I get it that you're a beginner (and I'm typing all this on this regard), but once you know enough to get started it's really both easier and faster to just "searched the web for *create dataset datatable datacolumn in code vb.net*".

This said, here are the basics:

```
Dim table As New DataTable
Dim col As New DataColumn("ColumnName", GetType(String))

table.Columns.Add(col)

Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(table)
```

Also, [here's a good place to read code snippets about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/). Official documentation is not to be underestimated in VB.NET.

Have fun.

Comment: I changed my first code. I tried to adapt this code but unfortunately I have only this error in this word ( FACTORY ) (DS.FACTORY.Rows.Add(dr.Cells(0).Value, dr.Cells(1).Value, dr.Cells(2).Value)) .. FACTORY is not a member of System.Data.Dataset

Comment: `FACTORY is not a member of System.Data.Dataset` means that there is no method or property in Dataset which is named FACTORY. You probably just want to access your datatable here, which you can do using the `Tables` property of your Dataset. Since there is only one table in your dataset, you can simply use the index zero, like this: `DS.Tables(0).Rows.` etc etc.

Comment: Thank you master for all.Yes I have no error now but I could not see the data of my DataGridView1 in my Crystal report1 page .When I click on Button1 I got this message (The report has no tables.) at this line "    rp.SetDataSource(DS.Tables("FACTORY")) ".Thank you very much for help

Comment: I just like helping people learn. The problem here is kinda the same than the last one. When you write DS.Tables("FACTORY")), you tell to the DataSet "Give me the table named "FACTORY". But you (probably) never named your table, so you get a Nothing. You can name your table by using `FACTORY.TableName = "FACTORY"`.

Comment: Knowing that there is only one Table in your DataSet, you could use the index instead: `DS.Tables(0)`. It's simple and I like simple.

Comment: Thank you laancelot for all and for your pricious time with me.i change my first code but always i have this error ( Report has no tables )..

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if this is a dataset manipulation problem or a crystal reports problem (and I'm not proficient with CR), so we'll need you to learn some debugging tricks to understand what's going on. Do you know about breakpoints? [Here are the basics.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2019#debug-the-app) The link speaks about C# but visual studio handles breakpoints the same for C# and VB.NET.

Comment: What you need to do is to verify if you are really passing the table to the crystal report object. You can do this by setting your breakpoint on the `rp.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))` line, then run the app and when it breaks use the mouse cursor and hover over the table you're giving to the `rp`. If there really is a table, you need help with crystal report. If there is a Nothing, you need to find how to pass your DataTable or where you drop it (either way let me know what you see).

Comment: Thank you for your precious time .. very nice of you.before all I just ask you .. what to add to the page CR.because i only add a page empty of CR.I did not add an XSD Dataset.I made a break point I add a picture in my first participation.Thank you laancelot

Comment: When you run your code, Visual Studio will stop on the line of your breakpoint. Then you can use your mouse cursor to verify if the table is passed to the report. [Here's how it looks when I do it.](https://imgur.com/a/0Yrmyiq) Of course, I don't see it inside the report itself, as I haven't installed it, but you should be able to du just like I did using your `rp.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))` line.

Comment: If you can see the table being passed to the report, then the problem lies with the report, which with I'm not proficient. Then you could make a new post, this time with a precise question and a short and reproductible example - which is kinda what you are doing right now, but just with me instead of the whole SO community.

Comment: Thank you a lot laancelot .. i added an new subject in titre ( Print DataGridView without Dataset : Xsd )

Comment: That's the idea. Good luck!