# Print DataGridView without Dataset : Xsd

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

With this code I want after query print what it is displayed on my DataGridView1 which displays 3 columns.I do not want to use Dataset Xsd and its DataTable. I added to my project an empty page of Crystalreport1.

With this code when i click on my Button1 i got this error "`The report has no tables.`" exactly in this line : `rp.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))`.

I asked in this subject but i not found the best result :
[Create DataColumns and Dataset witout database by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55825226/create-datacolumns-and-dataset-witout-database-by-code)
This is all My code :

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim FACTORY As New DataTable
    FACTORY.TableName = "FACTORY"
    Dim col1 As New DataColumn("FirstName", GetType(String))
    Dim col2 As New DataColumn("LastName", GetType(String))
    Dim col3 As New DataColumn("Phone", GetType(String))
    FACTORY.Columns.Add(col1)
    FACTORY.Columns.Add(col2)
    FACTORY.Columns.Add(col3)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DS.Tables.Add(FACTORY)

    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        DS.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr.Cells(0).Value, dr.Cells(1).Value, dr.Cells(2).Value)
    Next

    'Dim rp1 As New CrystalReport1
    'rp1.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))
    'rp.SetDataSource(DataGridView1.DataSource)
    'Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rp
    'Form1.ShowDialog()


    Dim Rp As New ReportDocument
    Rp.Load("E:\SABRINE\CrystalReport1.rpt")
    Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Rp
    Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    Form1.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After you added a crysta report viewer to your app, you have to add a new form a crystal report and add there your datasource.
After creating a report with your datasource. you add this new crystal reort to your rp object rp.Load("crystalrport path\yourcrystal.rpt")
ad then add your datasource.
Describbed here http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_step_by_step.htm

or as video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iN2yjEWs-So

Comment: Thank you very very much nbk for help.it's true now I did not get an error message but the report will appear completely empty without any data even though my DataGridView1 is filled with 3 columns.I changed the code used in my first post.

Comment: Crystal Report is only needed when you have big or complicated Reports. For a one Table Report you can also use microsofts rdl https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/publishing-data-sources-and-reports?view=sql-server-2017   but still you have to folow all steps.

Comment: Thank you very much.I know a little handle reports with Tables with DataBase .. I know very well the steps .. my misfortune here .. there is not a database access .. also I do not have a table access .. I just want to print what it displays on DataGridView1 .. it's my problem